# Conditionally Define a Variable

Tags: go

In javascript we can do this:

```
var x string = expr1 || expr2
```

If `expr1` is not `undefined`, it will be copied to `x`, if it is `undefined`, `expr2` will be copied to `x`. In go, we can use:

```
if expr1 == "" { var string x = expr1 } else { var string x = expr2 }
```

Is there are shorthand for this? If not, why?

Comment: go is statically typed. Everything must be declared at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the "why" however you can always use this :

```
var a []string = expr1

if a == nil {
    a = expr2
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Declarations and scope](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)
>
> A declaration binds a non-blank identifier to a constant, type,
>   variable, function, label, or package. Every identifier in a program
>   must be declared.
>
> [The zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When memory is allocated to store a value, either through a
>   declaration or a call of make or new, and no explicit initialization
>   is provided, the memory is given a default initialization. Each
>   element of such a value is set to the zero value for its type: false
>   for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings, and nil
>   for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

---

> [Type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system)
>
> [Static type-checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type-checking)
>
> [Dynamic type-checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_type-checking_and_runtime_type_information)

---

Go is a statically typed language. All variables must be declared at compile time and they have an well-defined initial value. JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. Variables are declared at run time. Therefore, the JavaScript construct makes no sense in Go.

Comment: I *think* he meant why can't you do `var expr1, expr2 = nil, "stuff"; var expr3 = expr1 || expr2` not why you can't use dynamic types.

Comment: @OneOfOne Yup! That is what I am trying to say! I still don't have an answer.

Comment: My answer is as close as you're gonna get, there's no other magical way to do it. You could use `interface{}` if expr1 and expr2 aren't the same type but then it gets messy from there.